# NullPointerException when using 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception

My goal is to traverse a maze using a stack, but I am unable to get very far.

I have a 2D array of `Room` objects and I always start at position 1,1. I believe I have everything set up correctly. However, I keep getting a `NullPointerException` whenever I try to access the data stored in my array.

Any assistance that will point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Here is my room class:

```
import java.awt.Point;


public class Room {
private Room up;
private Room down;
private Room left;
private Room right;
private char value;
private boolean blocked;
private boolean visited = false;
private Point p;

public void setCord(int row, int column) {
p = new Point(row, column);
}

public void setUp(Room [][] r, int row, int column) {
up = r[row][column];    
}


public void setDown(Room[][] r, int row, int column) {
down = r[row][column];

}

public void setRight(Room[][] r, int row, int column) {

right = r[row][column];
}

public void setLeft(Room[][] r, int row, int column) {

left = r[row][column];
}

public void setValue(char c) {

value = c;
}

public void setVisited(boolean b) {
visited = b;
} 
public void setBlocked(boolean b) {
blocked = b;
}

public Point getCord() {
return p;
}

public Room getUp() {
return up;  
}


public Room getDown() {
return down;
}

public Room getRight() {

return right;
}

public Room getLeft() {

return left;
}

public char getValue() {

return value;
}
public boolean getVisited() {
return visited;
} 

public boolean getBlocked() {
return blocked;
}


}
```

Here is my maze class:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Maze {
String inFile,              // Name of file to be used as input
       outFile,             // Name of file to output completed maze to
       line;                // Current line being read by scanner
    char [][] mazeContent;  
    Room [][] rooms;// Holds the values that create maze
    Room [] theStack;
    Room current = new Room();
    ArrayList<Room> al;
    int rows, columns;
    int tos = 0;
    char [][] mazeC;

    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
    Maze m = new Maze();
    }

    public Maze() throws FileNotFoundException {
        // Prompts user for the name of the file they wish to use as the input file.
        inFile = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the name of the file you wish to read, including " +
        "the file path:");
        //if(inFile.equals("")) inFile = "C:\Java\JavaFiles\maze1.txt;
        // Prompts user to enter the name they wish to save the file under.
        outFile = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the filename you wish to save the data to:");
        // Creates a scanner object to read in the input file.
        Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(inFile));
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(outFile);  
        rows = readFile.nextInt();
        columns = readFile.nextInt();
        readFile.nextLine();
        theStack = new Room[1000];
        mazeContent = new char [rows][columns];
        rooms = new Room [rows][columns];
        theStack = new Room[1000];

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        line = readFile.nextLine();
        for(int j = 0; j< line.length(); j++) {
        mazeContent[i][j]  = line.charAt(j);        
        }
        }

        createRooms();
        findPath();
    }


    private void findPath() {
    Room start = rooms[1][1];
    push(start);
        while(!isEmpty()) { 
    current = pop();
    //System.out.println("The value is " + current.getValue());
    if(current.getValue() == '$') {
        System.out.println("Success");
    }
    else if(current.getBlocked() != true && current.getVisited() != true) {
                current.setVisited(true);
                push(current.getRight());
                push(current.getLeft());
                push(current.getUp());
                push(current.getDown());
    }
    }
    }

    public void createRooms() {
    for(int i = 1; i < rows - 1; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j < columns -1; j++) {
                Room r = new Room();
                r.setCord(i,j);
                r.setValue(mazeContent[i][j]);
                r.setUp(rooms, i-1, j);
                r.setDown(rooms, i+1, j);
                r.setRight(rooms, i, j+1);
                r.setLeft(rooms, i, j-1);
                if(mazeContent[i][j] == '*')
                    r.setBlocked(true);
                else
                    r.setBlocked(false);
                rooms[i][j] = r;
    }
    }
    }

    private Room pop() {
    return theStack[--tos];
    }

    private boolean isEmpty() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return tos == 0;
    }

    private void push(Room item) {
    if (isFull()) {
    System.out.println("The stack is full!");

    }
    else 
        theStack[tos++] = item;
    }

    private boolean isFull() {

    return tos == theStack.length-1;
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah and show us on which line you get the NPE

Comment: Few people are going to bother to decipher your code above.  But the reason you're getting a "null pointer" exception is because you are (duh!) referencing an object reference (pointer) that is null, either because you never set it or because you set it to null explicitly.  A little debugging should tell you WHICH object reference is null, and then you can work backwards from there.  Few people here are going to do your work for you.

Comment: I know what the null pointer exception means i am just not sure why it is giving me one on this line. It is happening in the maze class on line: if(current.getValue() == '$') { but it is doing it anytime i am trying to access the values stored in a room object. I am setting all of these values in the create room method so they should not be null.

Comment: Duh!  Maybe `current` is null.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely root cause of your NullPointerException is that you have not (fully) initialized something.  Perhaps a field of one of your objects.  Perhaps an element of on of your arrays.  When you then try to use this uninitialized field or array element, you are actually trying to perform an operation on a `null` reference ... and that causes the exception.

---

If the exception is being thrown by

```
    if(current.getValue() == '$')
```

then that means that `current` is `null`.  That means that you "popped" a `null` from your stack.  On first sight, the implementations of your stack operations look OK, so my guess is that somewhere you have pushed a `null`.

My suggestion is to add a test in the `push` method that throws an exception if you attempt to push `null`.  (Or try and track this down using a debugger.)  Then continue working backwards to figure out where the `null` came from.